# Can a Bashscript disown itself, and then kill the script that launched it in the first place?

Tags: bash

script1.sh

```
script2.sh #launch another script
sudo reboot #reboot computer
```

script2.sh

```
# disown myself from script1
pkill script2.sh # hence preventing the reboot
# continue doing other stuff, even after the parent is dead
```

If possible, how is this done?

Comment: You can use `nohup` to keep the child process from dying when the parent process exits.

Comment: How about just modifying script1 to do the disown (by `(script2.sh&)`) and then delete the reboot command?

Comment: @JohnZwinck There are reasons to why this is not possible in this specific case. Long story short… It's a Raspberry far away, not allowing incoming connections. So all it does is looking for a script on a server, and if it finds it it runs it. I need the script it finds and runs, to cancel the script that found it.

Comment: @Sneftel Can this be run from the child process, keeping the child process from dying even after the child process pkills the parent process?

Comment: It can't keep itself alive (as far as I know), but it can start its own child process which will stay alive when it's been killed.

Comment: The Child could look for the parents pid, kill it and then the child would be linked to init

Comment: @Jidder How would the child kill parents pid, without being killed itself?

Comment: Because it becomes orphaned and gets assigned to init as its parent

Comment: @Jidder So if a child pkills its parent, the child process is still held alive assigned to init? Automatically?

Comment: Yes, if you kill the parents pid. Look here stackoverflow.com/questions/8533377/…. Also read the init man page `init is the parent of all processes on the system, it is executed by the kernel and is responsible for starting all other processes; it is the parent of all processes whose natural parents have died and it is responsible for reaping those when they die.`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disown the child script:

```
$ cat parent.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'Parent start'
./child.sh
echo 'Parent end'
$ cat child.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'Child start'
kill $PPID
sleep 1
echo 'Child end'
$ ./parent.sh 
Parent start
Child start
Terminated
$ Child end
```

So the parent is terminated by the child, and one second later the child runs its own last line. The child has simply been reparented to the `init` process. If you up the timeout you can see the entry in the process table:

```
$ ps a | grep '[.]sh'
 9752 pts/1    S      0:00 bash ./child.sh
```

Comment: He doesnt want to kill the child

Comment: It continues running here, even if I include a sleep. Edited to show this and add an explanation.